# Left join with where and like

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query i using with a php search code the problem is on localhost this query work and give me the result i need but online i receive this message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'where tbl_project.db_projectname like '%saida%' or
>   tbl_project.db_location lik' at line 30

php code

```
 $qq=array();
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){  
    $search =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['search']); 
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_projectname like '%".$search."%' ";  
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_location like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_client like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_offer like '%".$search."%' ";    
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_sheet like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_invoice like '%".$search."%' ";
    $qq[] = "tbl_project.db_po like '%".$search."%' ";
    } 
$second=true;
   foreach($qq as $qu){  
        if($second){  
        $sq .= " where  ".$qu;      
        $second = false;  
        }else{$sq .= " or ".$qu;}} 
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT
    tbl_project.db_id,
    tbl_project.db_projectname,
    tbl_project.db_location,
    tbl_project.db_client,
    tbl_project.db_transferredto,
    tbl_project.db_psd,
    tbl_project.db_pdd,
    tbl_project.db_duration,
    tbl_project.db_past,
    tbl_project.db_padd,
    tbl_project.db_aduration,
    tbl_project.db_percent,
    tbl_project.db_pnote,
    tbl_project.db_user,
    tbl_project.db_cpercentage,
    tbl_project.db_epercentage,
    tbl_project.db_mpercentage,
    tbl_project.db_status,
    tbl_project.db_offer,
    tbl_project.db_sheet,
    tbl_project.db_invoice,
    tbl_project.db_po,
    sum(
        tbl_activities.db_totalcost
    ) AS total_cost
FROM
    tbl_project
LEFT JOIN tbl_activities ON tbl_project.db_projectname = tbl_activities.db_projectname
{$sq} GROUP BY tbl_project.db_id")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

/********************************

```
SELECT tbl_project.db_id, tbl_project.db_projectname, tbl_project.db_location, tbl_project.db_client, tbl_project.db_transferredto, tbl_project.db_psd, tbl_project.db_pdd, tbl_project.db_duration, tbl_project.db_past, tbl_project.db_padd, tbl_project.db_aduration, tbl_project.db_percent, tbl_project.db_pnote, tbl_project.db_user, tbl_project.db_cpercentage, tbl_project.db_epercentage, tbl_project.db_mpercentage, tbl_project.db_status, tbl_project.db_offer, tbl_project.db_sheet, tbl_project.db_invoice, tbl_project.db_po, sum( tbl_activities.db_totalcost ) AS total_cost FROM tbl_project LEFT JOIN tbl_activities ON tbl_project.db_projectname LIKE tbl_activities.db_projectname where tbl_project.db_id='79' where tbl_project.db_projectname like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_location like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_client like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_offer like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_sheet like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_invoice like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_po like '%saida%' GROUP BY tbl_project.db_id
```

Comment: it would be nice if you paste entire query

Comment: @daniherculano check above please

Comment: you have two 'where' condition. Use 'and' to replace 2nd

Comment: @daniherculano is their another method to create the query to search the problem is with the total cost is in a table and the project on another table i want if he put 't' all project with t appear and appear the total cost in my query i have a problem

Answer (score 0):

You have added two "where" clause.

```
SELECT tbl_project.db_id, tbl_project.db_projectname, 
tbl_project.db_location, tbl_project.db_client, 
tbl_project.db_transferredto, 
tbl_project.db_psd, tbl_project.db_pdd, tbl_project.db_duration, 
tbl_project.db_past, tbl_project.db_padd, tbl_project.db_aduration, 
tbl_project.db_percent, tbl_project.db_pnote, tbl_project.db_user, 
tbl_project.db_cpercentage, tbl_project.db_epercentage, 
tbl_project.db_mpercentage, tbl_project.db_status, tbl_project.db_offer,
tbl_project.db_sheet, tbl_project.db_invoice, tbl_project.db_po, 
sum( tbl_activities.db_totalcost ) AS total_cost FROM tbl_project
LEFT JOIN tbl_activities ON tbl_project.db_projectname 
LIKE tbl_activities.db_projectname where tbl_project.db_id='79'
and tbl_project.db_projectname like '%saida%' or    
tbl_project.db_location 
like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_client like '%saida%' or 
tbl_project.db_offer 
like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_sheet like '%saida%' or 
tbl_project.db_invoice 
like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_po like '%saida%' GROUP BY  
tbl_project.db_id
```

Answer (score -2):

Use "LIKE" instead of "=" in the left Join section so it will be

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_activities ON tbl_project.db_projectname LIKE tbl_activities.db_projectname
{$sq} GROUP BY tbl_project.db_id")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: same message You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where tbl_project.db_projectname like '%saida%' or tbl_project.db_location lik' at line 30

Comment: Please use "echo $sq" to show your query then you can see the syntaxe error exactly

Comment: you can check above please